# Inserting into SQL Server from select

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I'm trying try to insert rows from my select statement. But I get a syntax error at the first `FROM` in the statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrganizationControlGroup]
    VALUES
    (
       OrganizationId,
       9999,
       NULL, 
       CONVERT(DATE,SYSDATETIME()),
       NULL,
       CONVERT(DATE,SYSDATETIME())
    )
    FROM 
    (   
        SELECT TOP 450  o.OrganizationId
        FROM Organization o
        WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (   
            SELECT * 
            FROM OrganizationControlGroup  c 
            WHERE c.OrganizationId = o.OrganizationId
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You can use `INSERT` either with `VALUES` and one (or in newer SQL Server versions more) single record expression list enclosed in parentheses, or with `SELECT`. If you use the `SELECT` variant, note that some column expressions can be constants or expressions like your `CONVERT(DATE,SYSDATETIME())` that do not depend on the source table. The correct version of your statement would be:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OrganizationControlGroup]
    SELECT TOP 450
       o.OrganizationId,
       9999,
       NULL, 
       CONVERT(DATE,SYSDATETIME()),
       NULL,
       CONVERT(DATE,SYSDATETIME())
    FROM Organization o
        WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (   
            SELECT * 
            FROM OrganizationControlGroup  c 
            WHERE c.OrganizationId = o.OrganizationId
        )
```

The documentation for `INSERT` is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Comment: @AntarrByrd And why don't you mark it as the answer then?

Comment: @GoRoS Sorry Got distracted